# Find two sequences$\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^n$, which $b_i = 1 - a_i$, $\prod_{i=1}^n b_i=0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible that two sequences $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where both $a_i$ and $b_i$ $\in[0,1]$, satisfy the relationship which $b_i = 1 - a_i$, and also $\prod_{i=1}^n b_i=0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but the only such sequences are those wherein exactly one $a_i$ equals $1$ and all others are $0$.

The condition $\prod_{i=1}^nb_i=0$ is equivalent to there being some $i$ with $b_i=0$. Let $i_0$ be such an $i$. Since $b_i=1-a_i$, we have $a_{i_0}=1$. This means the sum of all the other $a_i$s must be zero. Since $a_i\in [0,1]$ for all $i$, this means that $a_i=0$ for all $i\neq i_0$.

Comment: Yes, $a_{i_0} = 1$ and $b_{i_0} = 0$, for $i \neq i_0$ $a_i = 0$ and $b_i = 1$, I didn't expect to be that obvious, but somehow being blind to this all the time. But it's the only possible way?

Comment: @KyuuCampanello Yes, it's the only way. My answer shows this.